# How to Combine Place Autocomplete and Draggable Directions

Tags: google-maps

These are the 2 samples i want to combine together:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

I am still learning and i do not know how to combine these two samples.
What i am planning to do is put an original location and destination location while showing text directions.

Please i am doing these on our school project . It would really mean a lot to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the draggable option to the marker and the right panel in the DirectionsRenderer like so:

`this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          draggable: true,
          map: map,
          panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
        });`

Here is an example of [both samples combined](https://jsfiddle.net/cbfgjhzs/)

Comment: Franco you are a lifesaver, you dont know how much you helped me .
Thank you so much . You will be credited once the project is done .

Comment: I have another question Franco, how do you make the destination input have a fixed value like a fixed address?

I was planning to add a value type in the destination input

 <input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a destination location" value="SM City Naga, Ninoy & Cory Aquino Avenue, Barangay Triangulo, Naga, Camarines Sur, Philippines">

But it does not work because the user need to click on the dropdown list
I want to make it automatically so it would be user friendly. Thanks

Comment: I see that my original answer has helped you. Please indicate that my answer was useful by voting. Also, this is a new question, please open a new question for this so can I answer it. Cheers.